# Как улучшить этот код?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```
function cet() {
    for (var j = 1; j < 15; ++j) {
        var el = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[j]
        el.onmouseover = function () {
            el.childNodes[1].style.display = "block"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: для чего этот код и зачем его улучшать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> для чего этот код и зачем его улучшать?

вот и первый ответ как улучшить код: сделать его понятным для окружающих

второе: вы 15 раз запрашиваете NodeList - никогда в циклах не запрашивайте NodeList!

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var j = elems.length; j >= 0; j--) {
    var el = elems[j];
    el.onmouseover = function () {
        el.childNodes[1].style.display = "block"
    }
}
```

**UPD:** переформулировал ответ

Comment: Надо бы наверное переформулировать, т.к. `elems.item(j)` тоже обращение к DOM. В оригинальном говнокоде запрашивался NodeList по условию, что очень толсто.

Comment: плохо знаком с принципами работы `.getElementsByTagName`, аналогичная операция на jQuery закешировала бы объект и обращения в `each`, например, не были бы обращениями к DOM